# Please help to optimize this regex

Tags: regex, capture-group

**Input:**

```
+ 1220     001d.a16a.9400    dynamic   0          F    F  Po10
* 1220     0021.f60f.4127    dynamic   0          F    F  Eth1/46
```

**Expression:**

```
\S+\s+(\d+)\s+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[.][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[.][0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1\t$2\t$3
```

**Output:**

```
1220    001d.a16a.9400  Po10
1220    0021.f60f.4127  Eth1/46
```

Comment: what language/tool do you use? Is the number of fields always the same?

Comment: what language and context.  What do you mean by optimize?  Does it do what you intend it to do?

Comment: if you are interested in reducing the amount of backtracking to achieve O(n) parsing, have a look at [Atomic Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) and [Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean shorten by "optimize", try this one:

Expression:

```
^.+?(\d+)\s+([^\s]+?)\s.+?([^\s]+)$
```

Replace:

```
$1\t$2\t$3
```

Maybe you have to use /m (Multiline) and /s (dot matches any char) switches.

PHP-Example:

```
<?php
  $sourcestring="+ 1220     001d.a16a.9400    dynamic   0          F    F  Po10";
  echo preg_replace('/^.+?(\d+)\s+([^\s]+?)\s.+?([^\s]+)$/ms','$1\t$2\t$3',$sourcestring);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @netblognet